# Simple statistical question. What are the odds that two people share a common interest?

Tags: statistics, combinations

This should be easy but I can't figure it out for some reason.  Let's say there are X clubs that people can become members of.  However, a single person has time for exactly N of them (where N is less than X.  So if X = 10, a person has time for N = 3 of them).  If you have two people, what are the odds that they share at least one club in terms of X and N.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The complementary event to "These people share at least one interest" is "These people have no interests in common".  It might be easier to compute the probability of the latter, then use that to find the former.

Comment: So I ended up getting 1 - { [((N - X)!)^2] / [N! * (N - 2X)!] }.  That seems complicated but it looks like its working out, can anyone help verify that I didn't screw something up?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more information about writing math on this site.  It will make life MUCH easier.  Assuming that I'm correctly translating what you've written as
$$
1-\frac{[(N-X)!]^2}{N!(N-2X)!},
$$
then you are right (but I would include a note of the form "where we define $z!=0$ for all $z<0$").

Comment: @Mark Alternatively, you could note first that the probability that two people have at least one interest in common is trivially 1 if $N<2X$ (think pidgeonhole principle), then handle this case with the assumption $N\geq 2X$.